# PHP - dynamic var in use()

Tags: php, variables, callback

How would you create a *dyanmic* (i.e. `${...}`) variable in a callback via `use()` that is readable to the outer scope?

I was surprised to discover that this throws a parse error.

```
$foo = [1,2,3];
array_walk($foo, function($val, $key) use (&${'val_'.$key}) { //<-- parse error in use()
    ${'val_'.$key} = $val;
});
$val_2; //I expected 3;
```

But the following does not - and the only difference is I use a named variable (`$bar`), not a dynamic one, in `use()`.

```
$foo = [1,2,3];
$bar = [];
array_walk($foo, function($val, $key) use (&$bar) { //<-- fine - using 'normal' variable
    $bar[$key] = $val;
});
$bar[2]; //3
```

This is a hypothetical question - I'm just wondering why the dynamic approach errors.

Comment: [There's a bug report here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62918), but it doesn't have a whole lot of information

Comment: Interesting comment on the bug page: "This is obvious syntax error. PHP does not support ${'x'} in script context. ${var} notation is only used for text context to distinguish text and variable." *Obviously*, eh? Not so obvious, I'd say.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make a whole of sense to me either - it seems like it should be perfectly valid. Not a common use-case by any means, so I'm not shocked it hasn't come up again.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug as per PHP team comments.

> [2013-06-29 20:15 UTC] yohgaki@php.net

```
-Status: Open
```

`+Status: Not a bug`

> [2013-06-29 20:15 UTC] yohgaki@php.net

```
$printGlob2 = function() use (${'x'}) {
```

> This is obvious syntax error. PHP does not support `${'x'}` in script
>   context.
>
> `${var}` notation is only used for text context to distinguish text and
>   variable.

[Reference in comments section](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62918&edit=3)

Comment: `PHP does not support ${'x'} in script context.` That isn't true though.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that, I posted the same link in the comments. But that isn't true.

Comment: i agree with you but PHP team mention that it's not a bug

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be the first time they were wrong